# How I can I parse comments from macro expansion using libclang?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, libclang

Given the following C++ program:

```cpp
#define SOME_MACRO \
  (void) x; /* some comment in macro */ \

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  /* some comment in main */
  SOME_MACRO
  SOME_MACRO
  return 0;
}
```

I would like libclang to call me back on the comments expanded in `SOME_MACRO`.

I tried the to register a comment handler, and set-up the preprocessor output options as follow:

```cpp
struct CommentPrinter : clang::CommentHandler {
  bool HandleComment(Preprocessor & pp, SourceRange comment) {
    llvm::outs() << "new comment : \n";
    comment.dump(pp.getSourceManager());
    return false;
  }
};

  struct frontend_t : clang::ASTFrontendAction
  {
    std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer>
      CreateASTConsumer(clang::CompilerInstance& CI,
          clang::StringRef source_file) override
      {
        CI.getPreprocessorOutputOpts().ShowComments = 1;
        CI.getPreprocessorOutputOpts().ShowMacroComments = 1;
        CI.getPreprocessor().addCommentHandler(new CommentPrinter);
        return std::make_unique<ast_consumer_t>();
      }
  };
```

But my comment handler was called only on comments line 2 and 7. Do you known if it is possible to be also called on comments on line 8 and 9?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.
The C++ standard  ([link to draft](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.3)) defines how files are processed in "translation phases". By the time the macro processor can get to work on your `#define` and macro expansions, the comments have already been removed:

> phase 3:
> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens ([lex.pptoken]) and sequences of whitespace characters (including comments).
> A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment.
> **Each comment is replaced by one space character.**
>
> phase 4:
> **Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and _­Pragma unary operator expressions are executed.**
> [...]
> All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

Comment: I agree on the standard with you. But with clang++, you can ask to preserve comments in macro using the `-CC` option (eg: `clang++ -E -CC foo.cpp`). This option, plus the fields in the `PreprocessorOutputOpts`, make me think there is a way.